# EF core 3.1 - common table for entity and owned type

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, domain-driven-design

I'm trying to implement DDD approach in my project but realized that I have too big aggregates and trying to minimize the amount of data loaded from the database. I have an aggregate **Order** which during some operations depends on another aggregate- **Company**. To perform operation **RefreshOrderNumber()** I need three properties from the Company entity and totally not interested in other fields from the **Company. So, I got an idea to create a value type for Order - **OrderCompanyInfo** and incapsulate those fields on it

```
public class Company
{
   public Id {get;private set;}
   public string Name {get; private set;}
   public string Currency {get; private set;}
   public string DocumentPrefix {get; private set;}
   // other ~15 fields
}

public class OrderCompanyInfo : ValuableType
{
   private OrderCompanyInfo ()
   {

   }
  
   public long CompanyId {get; private set;}
   public string Name {get; private set;}
   public string Currency {get; private set;}
   public string DocumentPrefix {get; private set;}
  
  public static OrderCompanyInfo Create(Company company)
  {
     return OrderCompanyInfo {
       CompanyId = company.Id,
       Name = company.Name,
       Currency = company.Currency ,
       DocumentPrefix = company.DocumentPrefix 
     }

  }
}

public class Order
{

  private Order()
  {
     
  }

  public Order(OrderCompanyInfo companyInfo)
  {
    CompanyInfo = companyInfo; 
    AddLog();
  }

  public OrderNumberInfo OrderNumber {get; private set;}
  public OrderCompanyInfo CompanyInfo {get; private set;}

 

  public void DoSomethingImportant()
  {
    RefreshOrderNumber();
    AddLog();
  }

  private void AddLog()
  {
     //Add log entry using CompanyInfo.Name
  }

  private void RefreshOrderNumber()
  {
     //Create new OrderNumberInfo using OrderCompanyInfo.Currency and OrderCompanyInfo.DocumentPrefix 
  }
}
```

Now I'm trying to make this works with EF core. Basically **OrderCompanyInfo** should be configured using **OwnOne()** method and mapped to the same table as **Company** entity has so the data always will be actual during Order aggregate loading through repositories. So I have this configuration for the Order aggregate:

```
public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Order> builder)
{
    builder.OwnsOne(x => x.InventoryOwnsCompanyProfile, opt =>
             {
                 opt.ToTable("Company"); 

                 opt.HasOne<Company>()
                    .WithOne()
                    .HasForeignKey<OrderCompanyInfo>(x => x.CompanyId);
             });
}
```

But trying this way gives me an error:

```
Cannot use table 'dbo.Company' for entity type 'OrderCompanyInfo ' since it is being used for entity type 'Company' and there is no relationship between their primary keys.
```

Is there any way to make EF core work in this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the answer was found on GitHub community.
https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/13162#issuecomment-417411405

They provided an example with two Entities which mapped to the same table

```
namespace One
{
    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Two
{
    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    }
}

public class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        => optionsBuilder
            .UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Test;ConnectRetryCount=0");

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<One.Person>(b =>
        {
            b.HasOne<Two.Person>().WithOne().HasForeignKey<Two.Person>(e => e.Id);
            b.ToTable("People");
            b.Property(e => e.Name).HasColumnName(nameof(One.Person.Name));
        });

        builder.Entity<Two.Person>(b =>
        {
            b.ToTable("People");
            b.Property(e => e.Name).HasColumnName(nameof(Two.Person.Name));
        });
    }
}
```

I was wrong trying to build **OrderCompanyInfo** as **Owned** type, cause owned type implies having relation from owned type to the owner. In my scenario, this will lead to the situation when **Company** table will have **OrderId** field, which is at least incorrect. Having OrderCompanyInfo entity configured through HasOne() suites me well